# Issues with using the native Windows SSTP client on Softether

Tags: softether

When trying to use SSTP with password authentication I'm unsuccesful at creating a connection from the native windows client. I always get MS-CHAPv2 authentication errors:

```
2015-01-03 03:04:43.278 On the TCP Listener (Port 443), a Client (IP address 1.2.3.4, Host name "1.2.3.4", Port number 51567) has connected.
2015-01-03 03:04:43.278 For the client (IP address: 1.2.3.4, host name: "something.be", port number: 51567), connection "CID-6" has been created.
2015-01-03 03:04:43.510 SSL communication for connection "CID-6" has been started. The encryption algorithm name is "RC4-MD5".
2015-01-03 03:04:44.194 SSTP PPP Session [1.2.3.4:51567]: A new PPP session (Upper protocol: SSTP) is started. IP Address of PPP Client: 1.2.3.4 (Hostname: "something.be"), Port Number of PPP Client: 51567, IP Address of PPP Server: 5.6.7.8, Port Number of PPP Server: 443, Client Software Name: "Microsoft SSTP VPN Client", IPv4 TCP MSS (Max Segment Size): 0 bytes
2015-01-03 03:04:45.613 On the TCP Listener (Port 0), a Client (IP address 1.2.3.4, Host name "something.be", Port number 51567) has connected.
2015-01-03 03:04:45.613 For the client (IP address: 1.2.3.4, host name: "something.be", port number: 51567), connection "CID-7" has been created.
2015-01-03 03:04:45.613 SSL communication for connection "CID-7" has been started. The encryption algorithm name is "(null)".
2015-01-03 03:04:45.613 [HUB "DEFAULT"] The connection "CID-7" (IP address: 1.2.3.4, Host name: something.be, Port number: 51567, Client name: "Microsoft SSTP VPN Client", Version: 4.12, Build: 9514) is attempting to connect to the Virtual Hub. The auth type provided is "External server authentication" and the user name is "test".
2015-01-03 03:04:45.613 [HUB "DEFAULT"] Connection "CID-7": User authentication failed. The user name that has been provided was "test".
2015-01-03 03:04:45.633 Connection "CID-7" terminated by the cause "User authentication failed." (code 9).
2015-01-03 03:04:45.633 Connection "CID-7" has been terminated.
2015-01-03 03:04:45.633 The connection with the client (IP address 1.2.3.4, Port number 51567) has been disconnected.
2015-01-03 03:04:45.915 SSTP PPP Session [1.2.3.4:51567]: "MS-CHAP v2" (Microsoft Challenge and Response Protocol Version 2.0) user authentication failed.
2015-01-03 03:04:45.915 SSTP PPP Session [1.2.3.4:51567]: A PPP protocol error occurred, or the PPP session has been disconnected.
2015-01-03 03:04:47.948 Connection "CID-6" terminated by the cause "Connection has been disconnected." (code 3).
2015-01-03 03:04:47.948 Connection "CID-6" has been terminated.
2015-01-03 03:04:47.948 The connection with the client (IP address 1.2.3.4, Port number 51567) has been disconnected.
```

It does work using the SoftEther client but I prefer the native Windows client as it's easier to set up.  The type of authentication I set up is just local user/password authentication. Installed on Debian.

Comment: How did you bring up those logs? I define my SoftEther SSTP connection on Windows 10, it isn't even progressing to the point of asking me for authentication.

Comment: Never mind, it turned out to be a Windows 10 issue. For some reason it can't set up any VPN connection at all. Windows 7 does it without issue. Fuck Windows.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is the login name. You can't define the user as "test", it needs to be "test@virtual-hub". Where virtual-hub is your configured hub for that particular user.

Comment: you sir, saved be a lot of time